# How to get 2 doughnut charts in one chart (chartjs)

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Thanks in advance guys :)

I want to display 2 doughnut charts side by side to compare stats from 2 different years. I want to have the same key and keep the data in the same `<canvas>`.

I dont want: 2 canvas, 1 chart in the canvas

```
<canvas id="chart1"></chart>
<canvas id="chart2"></chart>
```

I do want: 1 canvas, 2 charts in the canvas

```
<canvas id="chart1"></chart>
```

Here's some JS to add context, this data adds 1 chart.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('chart1').getContext('2d');
var chart1 = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: ['1', '2', '3'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Pie',
            data: [12, 9, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
               'rgb(0,51,10)',
               'rgb(02,11,191)',
               'rgb(98,18,08)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        cutoutPercentage: 75,
        responsive: false
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 canvas on 1 page - see here:

```
<body>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Chart1</th>
    <th>Chart2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>

     <div style="width: 50%">
    <canvas id="canvas1" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
     </div>

    </td>
    <td>

  <div style="width: 50%">
    <canvas id="canvas2" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
  </div>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


</body>
```

---

```
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [
        {
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
        },  
            {
                label: '# of Points',
                data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
                borderWidth: 1
            }
        ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
                    reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
var options2 = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [
        {
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
        },  
            {
                label: '# of Points',
                data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
                borderWidth: 1
            }
        ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
                    reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}


var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas1').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
var ctx2 = document.getElementById('canvas2').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx2, options2);
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michastg29/L138td4w/4/)

Comment: I'm looking to have 2 different pie circle charts rendered in one canvas.

Comment: I've tried a few alternatives, I think you're right on that one

Comment: Maybe it is easier with D3.js see here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kK5kKA-0PUQ